# form not posting to iframe back

Tags: javascript, authorize.net

This should have been pretty simple but I have spent a few hours trying to figure out why a simple form post would not end up in the iframe instead of a new window.

I am trying to post data to authorize.net and I want the reponse to be back in the iframe. However it opens a new window. I am not sure what else to do. here is my code

```
<html>  
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            document.getElementById("test-form").submit();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>  

   <form method="post" name="test-form" id="test-form" target="myIframe" action="https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll">
   <input type="text" name="x_login">
   <input type="text" name="x_fp_sequence">
   <input type="text" name="x_fp_timestamp">
   <input type="text" name="x_amount">
   <input type="text" name="x_fp_hash">
   <input type="text" name="x_show_form">
   <input type="text" name="x_test_request">
   <input type="text" name="x_type">
   <input type="text" name="x_currency_code">
   <input type="text" name="x_invoice_num">
   <input type="text" name="x_description">
   <input type="text" name="x_first_name">
   <input type="text" name="x_last_name">
   <input type="text" name="x_company">
   <input type="text" name="x_address">
   <input type="text" name="x_city">
   <input type="text" name="x_state">
   <input type="text" name="x_zip">
   <input type="text" name="x_country">
   <input type="text" name="x_phone">
   <input type="text" name="x_email">
   <input type="text" name="x_relay_response">
   <input type="text" name="x_solution_id">
   </form>
   <iframe src="" name="myIframe></iframe>  

</body>  



</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By putting your code in Plunker, there is a syntax error at line 37:

```html
<iframe src="" name="myIframe></iframe>  
                             ^-- missing "
```

After adding the closing quote, I can see the page loaded in the iFrame :)
https://embed.plnkr.co/aM5EsESHODV8nPbVhyK8/

You may want to consider changing to use an IDE which may help you identifying typos, so that hours can be saved.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing double quotes at the end of the iframe name.